# Dynamically update/display the content on the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I recently completed the Javascript course on Codecademy. One of the assignments was to create a choose your own adventure program. The program is quite basic, and now after completing the course, I am looking for ways to optimize its performance. What I'd like to do is, instead of using prompts, maybe use an input text box or even a 'yes/no' button. The catch is that I do not want a bunch of separate HTML files for each part of the story. Is it possible to dynamically update/display the content on the HTML page based on how the user answers the question. Can this be done with simple Javascript or jQuery?

```
var troll = prompt("You're walking through the forest, minding your own business, and you run into a troll! Do you FIGHT him, PAY him, or RUN?").toUpperCase();

switch(troll) {
    case 'FIGHT':
        var strong = prompt("How courageous! Are you strong (YES or NO)?").toUpperCase();
        var smart = prompt("Are you smart?").toUpperCase();
        if(strong === 'YES' || smart === 'YES') {
            console.log("You only need one of the two! You beat the troll--nice work!");
        } else {
            console.log("You're not strong OR smart? Well, if you were smarter, you probably wouldn't have tried to fight a troll. You lose!");
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: This can be done in javascript. You can use `document.getElementById` in javascript if you don't want to use a Js library.

Answer (score 3):

Well done on your `javascript` progress so far.

> Is it possible to dynamically update/display the content on the HTML page

Yes. You can get a really long way with these **5 functions**:

- `document.createElement();` (http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- `document.createTextNode();` (http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode)
- `[ELEMENT].setAttribute();` (http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)
- `[NODE].appendChild();` (http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- `[NODE].insertBefore();` (http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

Answer (score 0):

Move the text to a div, and use hide/show the part as you want:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
if(strong === 'YES' || smart === 'YES') {
    div1.style.display = 'block';        
    div2.style.display = 'none';
} else {
    div1.style.display = 'none'; 
    div2.style.display = 'block';
}
```